# django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'lab_equipment.lab_add' doesn't exist")

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to delete objects stored on the database from the Django admin page and I have gotten the below error:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'lab_equipment.lab_add' doesn't exist")
```

**Views**

```py
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.http import JsonResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse
from .forms import *
from .models import *

# Create your views here.


def main(request):
    return render(request, 'Lab/Lab.html')


def generateView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':  # If the form has been submitted...
        esrl = Esrl_form(request.POST) # Create a form instance
        equ = equipment(request.POST)
        num = count_form(request.POST)
        add = Add_form(request.POST)
        if esrl.is_valid() and equ.is_valid() and num.is_valid() and add.is_valid():  # All validation rules pass
            print("all validation passed")
            loc = esrl.save()
            e = equ.save(commit=False)
            c = num.save(commit=False)
            a = add.save(commit=False)  # not to save and connect the Foreign key
            e.location_number = loc  # b.foreignkeytoA = a Connecting foreign key
            e.save()
            c.equipment_name = e
            c.loc_num = loc
            c.save()
            a.location_number = loc  
            a.equipment_name = e
            a.stock = c 
            a.save()
            
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('home'))
        else:
            print("failed")

    else:     # if the request method is not post then create a form instance u if the request method is not post then create a form instance and loaded in the templatenloaded in the template
        esrl = Esrl_form
        equ = equipment
        num = count_form
        add = Add_form
    return render(request, 'Lab/Add.html', {   # Sending multiple forms to the HTML page
        'esrl': esrl,
        'equ': equ,
        'num': num,
        'add':add,
    })
```

**Model**

```py
from django.db import models
import uuid

# Create your models here.


class Esrl(models.Model):
    location_number = models.CharField(
        max_length=15)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.location_number


class ESRLequipmentinfo(models.Model):
    equipment_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    location_number = models.ForeignKey(Esrl, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.equipment_name


class count(models.Model):
    stock = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    equipment_name = models.ForeignKey(
        ESRLequipmentinfo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    loc_num = models.ForeignKey(Esrl, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        string = str(self.stock)
        return  str(self.loc_num) ,string, self.equipment_name


class move(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    location_number = models.ForeignKey(Esrl, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    equipment_name = models.ForeignKey(
        ESRLequipmentinfo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    stock = models.ForeignKey(count, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class add(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    location_number = models.ForeignKey(Esrl, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    equipment_name = models.ForeignKey(
        ESRLequipmentinfo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    stock = models.ForeignKey(count, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class History(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    Previous_location = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    new_location = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    euipment_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    equipment_count = models.IntegerField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

**Forms**

```py
from django import forms
from .models import *


class Esrl_form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Esrl
        fields = '__all__'
        template_name = 'Lab/Add.html'


class equipment(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ESRLequipmentinfo  # Esrl,count
        fields = ('equipment_name',)
        template_name = 'Lab/Add.html'
        # fields = '__all__'


class count_form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = count
        fields = ('stock',)
        template_name = 'Lab/Add.html'
        # fields = '__all__'


class Add_form(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = add
            fields = ('name',)
            template_name = 'Lab/Add.html'
```

**Settings**

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'Lab_equipment',
        'USER': '###',
        'PASSWORD': '###',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

1. I tried commenting out the code and run

```bash
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate -fake
```

But this didn't work.

2)And tried using:

```bash
python manage.py dbshell
```

This gave me the below error:

```
CommandError: You appear not to have the 'mysql' program installed or on your path.
```

I am using Mac os, I pip3 installed `MySQL-python`, `pymysql`, `mysqlclient` on my virtual environment, and locally upon running MySQL I get `mysql not found` error.
As well as, I have given all permissions to MySQL.

**Modules**

```
Django==3.2.6,
django-bootstrap-form==3.4,
mysql==0.0.3,
mysql-client==0.0.1,
mysql-connector-python==8.0.26,
mysqlclient==2.0.3,
PyMySQL==1.0.2,
sqlparse==0.4.1,
toml==0.10.2.
```

Comment: That error tells you that migrations have not been run. That means: Your python code in models.py does not match your DB-Structure. You will need to run makemigrations your_app to solve the problem.

Comment: run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` to apply your models changes to the actual database

Comment: I after running `python manage.py makemigrations AppName` resulted in 'No changes detected in app'.  `python manage.py migrate`  gave me 'No migrations to apply.' I tried to delete objects from the database and got the same result.

Answer (score 2):

Reviewing the database with my SQL workbench the table lab_add was not created during my initial migrations.
**The solution was to manually comment out create model command from 0001_initial.py file in the migrations folder**

```
from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='count',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('stock', models.IntegerField()),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Esrl',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('location_number', models.CharField(max_length=15)),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='ESRLequipmentinfo',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('equipment_name', models.CharField(max_length=40)),
                ('created_date', models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)),
                ('location_number', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='Lab.esrl')),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='History',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('name', models.CharField(max_length=150)),
                ('Previous_location', models.CharField(max_length=40)),
                ('new_location', models.CharField(max_length=40)),
                ('euipment_name', models.CharField(max_length=40)),
                ('equipment_count', models.IntegerField()),
                ('created_date', models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='move',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('name', models.CharField(max_length=150)),
                ('created_date', models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)),
                ('equipment_name', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='Lab.esrlequipmentinfo')),
                ('location_number', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='Lab.esrl')),
                ('stock', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='Lab.count')),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='count',
            name='equipment_name',
            field=models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='Lab.esrlequipmentinfo'),
        ),
        # commenting on this section will force Django to create this
        # table after running makemigrations


        # migrations.CreateModel(
        #     name='add',
        #     fields=[
        #         ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
        #         ('name', models.CharField(max_length=150)),
        #         ('created_date', models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)),
        #         ('equipment_name', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='Lab.esrlequipmentinfo')),
        #         ('location_number', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='Lab.esrl')),
        #         ('stock', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='Lab.count')),
        #     ],
        # ),
    ]
```

Commenting on the table which was not created during `initial python manage.py makemigrations` I ran the command again then ran `python manage.py migrate` everything was working fine.